# Selecting columns for copying Pandas DataFrame

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe, data-manipulation

I would like to copy my existing `df` to another pandas dataframe. Basically if I need to specify columns and copy-then it's easy and can be done in such a manner:

```
df_copy = df[['col_A', 'col_B', 'col_C']].copy()
```

But is it possible to copy only the other columns which not specified using this approach? I tried that way but it seems to be wrong:

```
df_copy = df[~df['col_A', 'col_B', 'col_C']].copy()
```

Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

How about that `df.columns.isin()` with preceding negation `~`?

```
df_copy_not = df[df.columns[~df.columns.isin(['col_A', 'col_B', 'col_C'])]]
```